# Can we declare a member variable of a class from jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

```
class Person{
 private int age;

 //rest body
}
```

Now my question is Can I declare another member variable say **String name** in class **Person** but not in java class, I want to declare it at runtime from **JSP** page may be inside **scriplet**.

Comment: You can't. What do you want to acheive by doing this? Explain what you want to do, so that we can propose something better.

Comment: i think what you want is to set the value on runtime , simply declare the variable in java class and set its value on runtime

Comment: first of all Thanks @JeevanPatil . Well It was just out of a curiosity attempt. Actually I just want to allocate memory to variable only if required. So this is what lead me to think in this manner..

Comment: You do know that JAVA is actually a static language(unlike scala or grovvy), which means you can not change(add,remove,update) class states and behaviors at run time by default. The work around is to use dynamic proxy, some libs support it such as cglib, javaassist. But before you jumping on it, think about it and think it twice, make sure you have a very strong reason for doing that.

Comment: thanks @HussainAkhtarWahid. Yeah that i know we can di like this but as i mentioned in above comment. This is what i am trying :)

Comment: thanks @spiritwalker.. This is something gr8 explaination.. Helped understanding the core logic perfectly... Liked it...  :)